# Best hardware/software solution for parallel makes?

Tags: build, makefile, smp

We've got a Linux-based build system in which a build consists of many different embedded targets (with correspondingly different drivers and featuresets enabled), each one built with another single main source tree.

Rather than try to convert our make-based system to something more multiprocess-friendly, we want to just find the best way to fire off builds for all of these targets simultaneously. What I'm not sure about is how to get the best performance.

I've considered the following possible solutions:

- Lots of individual build machines. Downsides: lots of copies of the shared code, or working from a (slow) shared drive. More systems to maintain.
- A smaller number of multiprocessor machines (dual quadcores, perhaps), with fast striped RAID local storage. Downsides: I'm unsure of how it will scale. It seems that the volume would be the bottleneck, but I don't know how well Linux handles SMP these days.
- A similar SMP machine, but with a hypervisor or Solaris 10 running VMware. Is this silly, or would it provide some scheduling benefits? Downsides: Doesn't address the storage bottleneck issue.

I intend to just sit down and experiment with these possibilities, but I wanted to check to see if I've missed anything. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a question more appropriate for serverfault.com.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure, since it's an infrastructure question, but on a topic programmers would know/care about. I'll try over there; thanks.

Comment: The build system aspects are definitely in the programming-domain, but the physical machine setup probably belong on Serverfault.com.

Comment: What size of the system are we talking about? How long does a build take?

Comment: A full build consists of ~200 megs of general source built for several targets (around 80). Each of the targets takes between 15 and 30 minutes to build, now. We've considered converting from plain GNU make, but that's a larger project with a lot of people to persuade. So for now, the plan is to just do as many of our builds at once as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as software solutions go, I can recommend [Icecream](http://en.opensuse.org/Icecream). It is maintained by SUSE and builds on distcc.

We used it very successfully at my previous company, which had similar build requirements to what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in fast incremental performance, then the cost of calculating the files which need to be rebuilt will dominate over the actual compile time and this will put higher demands on efficient I/O between the machines.

However, if you're mostly interested in fast full rebuilds (nightly builds, for example), then you may be better of rsyncing out the source tree to each build slave, or even have each build slave check out its own copy from source control. A CI-system such as Hudson would help to manage each of the slave build servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Our problem is the second one, from a build & release perspective. The size of the source makes a little unwieldy copying it out for every build, but it's certainly possible on a fast network. We've been using Hudson (and are looking at other build systems like AnthillPro), but we're wondering how to most effectively expand our build farms.

Comment: That's definitely a question for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

If your makefiles are sufficiently complete and well-structured, the `-j` flag may also be useful in overcoming I/O bottlenecks, if your build machine(s) have enough memory. This lets make run multiple independent tasks in parallel, so that your CPUs will ideally never block waiting on I/O. Generally, I've found good results by allowing several more tasks than I have CPUs in a machine.

It's not clear from your question if your current makefiles are not amenable to this, or if you just don't want to jump to something entirely different than make.